Worker Permission Message on Mac
I created a worker project with C# with .Net Core 7.0 to run on macOs environments as bacground service. I launch this project with plist. Later, when I open any application, I encounter the following permission message. How do I grant Full Disk Access to Plist?
Permission error of my worker service   image
Plist of my worker service image
sudo cp "$libDirectory"/com.x.resource.manager.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.x.resource.manager.plist

this code start my worker.
When I want to give full disk access permission to file in the plist that happens   image
All I want is make that permission message dont show,
thanks already
